# Put table saw table on wheels

Tags: table-saw

I would like to put this table on 2 wheels so I can wheel it around and move it outside to my patio.

[image]

[image]

I have these but not sure how to mount them on the legs.

[image]

**Edit:** Thanks for the suggestions, here's what I did:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Cut a sheet of plywood so that all 4 legs fit on it.
2. Mount the wheels to the plywood.
3. Set the saw on top of the plywood.
4. Fasten the legs to the plywood so the saw won't fall off.  I suggest some "L" brackets and screws through the legs but other means could be devised.

Comment: The only downside to this is that it increases the operating height... a plywood tray with the bottom of the wheels near the bottom of the tray would be ideal.

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate An increase in operating height would be ideal for my case.

Comment: +1 But you need a way to immobilize the table, e.g., locking wheels. Otherwise, as you feed stock, the saw will move.

Answer (score 7):

Just putting two casters (or four) on the table seems like a bad idea. The table will be lopsided and even if you raise the other two legs, the table will still have a tendency to move when you're cutting large pieces. If you're dead set on adding wheels, install four with locking features on a board and then secure the table to the board.

Comment: Yep, there needs to be a reliable locking feature, so the saw can't scoot out from under your workpiece.

Answer (score 5):

Attach two fairly large wheels near the bottom of two adjacent legs, but on the side of the leg. The wheel should almost be touching the ground (1/8" or 1/16"). When you want to move it, you simply tilt it towards the wheels until they touch and the weight is transferred. You can then roll it.  Conceptually, it is like a dolly. This might require additional bracing for the frame as those frames are built for vertical loads.

FYI, they do make products specifically to do this with a table saw. If money is not that much of an issue, you might want to internet search "table saw stand with wheels"